# Wordpress doesn't always load css

Tags: css, wordpress

My site is running with the last version of Wordpress and 15zine as a theme.

Sometimes when I surf through the pages Wordpress doesn't load the CSS correctly so I can see only the simple HTML page without the right formatting.

I've found out that these kinds of problems are usually caused by bad use of minimization and merging of cache plugins.

I would suggest to first disable both and start enabling only the minification. If it correctly works, I would go ahead with merging. With HTTP/2 merging is less needed

Comment: Nothing. I'm asking because I don't know how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your website multiple times and while some of the css (file: 822cc.css) does take a while to load, it does in fact load every time.

The issue may be on your side. Maybe open developers tools go to settings, under network click "Disable cache" and then reload the site a couple of times and see if the problem still exists.

Remember to keep developer tools open when doing this. You can even click the Network tab and then select the CSS button, hit f5 and see the files loading.

Comment: I have the same problem surfing with safari or chrome on iPad and also other normal users have this problem... I'll try to do as you said

Comment: I have found out that the problem is causated by a CSS that launch this error ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED. I have seen that a miniffy error. I use W3 Total cache